# Truncating multiple tables in a Oracle PL/SQL block fails

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, truncate

Running the following script:

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user = db_user, password = db_pwd, dsn = 'TULSA').
cur = conn.cursor()

sql = ("""  
        BEGIN
            truncate table shop_ord_temp;
            truncate table shop_ord_item_temp;
            truncate table shop_cust_temp;
        END;
    """)

cur.execute(sql)
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Receiving this error while running this anonymous block:

```
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06550: line 3, column 22:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "TABLE" when expecting one of the following:

   := . ( @ % ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
sql = ("""  
        BEGIN
            execute immediate 'truncate table shop_ord_temp';
            execute immediate 'truncate table shop_ord_item_temp';
            execute immediate 'truncate table shop_cust_temp';
        END;
    """)
```

This is a PL/SQL feature, not related to Python.